# TMainMenu Icons disappears after placing a TMemo on the form

Tags: delphi, icons

I got a TMainMenu with Icons. All is fine until i place a TMemo on the form. When i run my program the icons were dissappeared. What happened and how can i fixx this problem?

[image]

[image]

I am using Delphi 2010 as IDE.

Comment: Only parent items, interesting.. Set the image trough an action as a workaround.

Comment: Can you please explain that solution deeper? I dont understand really what you are try to say me...

Comment: problem only in disign-time or also in run-time? Did u install all Delphi 2010 updates?

Comment: Also in runtime. I installed Delphi 2010 Update 1 and Update 2. Using for the Icons a TImageList.

Comment: @The - A TAction I mean..

Comment: @The - I'm not sure if "does not work" is addressed to my comment, if it is, it works here.

Comment: DoubleBuffered = true?

Comment: Also happens in D7, but only if using TImageList... assigning Bitmap directly on MenuItem has no problems. And only happens in runtime. And doesn't happens if TMemo is created in runtime.

Comment: The memo cause a premature handle acquisition on the form - before the reader reads the menu - while setting the memo text as streamed from the dfm.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I'd really appreciate it if you told us how did you debug this. Where in the VCL does the properties get streamed from the DFM?

Comment: @Gabriel - Well, you debugged fine, but didn't go backwards as much. I mostly used the call stack..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is as Sertac described. The streaming of the memo's text is causing the icon to be lost from the menu bar.

So the simplest and most expedient solution is to make sure that the memo does not have text in its .dfm file. Set the text at runtime after the form has been created. For instance in the constructor, or in an `OnCreate` event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging the VCL, I tracked the issue to be on the `TMenuItem.AppendTo` procedure. The image isn't displayed when the variable `IsOwnerDraw` is set to `False`, and that happens when `GetImageList` returns `Nil`, in this case. Maybe this is a bug on the VCL, but setting `OwnerDraw = True` in TMainMenu solves the problem.

EDIT: Considering that `OwnerDraw = True` creates a problem with overlapping captions, I suggest you set Bitmap property of the parent TMenuItems to any bitmap as a workaround. This Bitmap will be ignored and the image in the TImageList will be read instead. You can then set `OwnerDraw = False` and the image will still be displayed.

Comment: Debugging further, it seems like `SetImages` (which sets the field `FImages` that will then be read by `GetImageList`) is only called after the parent items are drawn.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, but i discovered this solution really earlier but it opened only a next door of problems. Look at this:http://i.imgur.com/ezWTSPC.png?1 The Captions overlap...

Comment: Maybe you should set Bitmap property of the parent items as a workaround. It worked fine here. The Bitmap gets ignored and the menu correctly displays the TImageList image, instead. And it doesn't overlaps. Of course, you should set `OwnerDraw = False`

Comment: @TheAllSeeingEye I've edited the answer to include this last suggestion to make it self-contained.

Comment: No, don't use `Bitmap`.

Comment: It forces owner draw. It also makes it impossible for you to manage icons using actions. It also makes it hard to do full 32bpp alpha icons. It's a sucky solution. Especially when a much simpler one exists.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If I haven't missed something when debugging, an associated TImageList also forces owner draw... and what's wrong with owner draw? And if you're using actions, you don't need any workarounds, as noted by Sertac in the first comment. I can't see how it's simpler to set Memo.Text in runtime (I'm not saying it's simpler to set Bitmap property... both seem equally simple). It's more elegant, for sure... but I see no drawbacks in using this solution, either.

Comment: It doesn't force owner draw on XP. It does on Vista+ because the Emba devs don't know what they are doing. And the Emba owner draw menus suck, see my many QC reports on that subject. Personally, my Vista+ menus are system drawn because I fixed my VCL. It does need a transformation of image list icon to PARGB32 bitmap, but that's not hard. But the drawbacks of using Bitmap are obvious. It stops you controlling things through actions, as I already said.